# Enabling support for pcmcia card after I install Gentoo Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, gentoo, pcmcia

I installed gentoo on an old laptop and everything seemed fine on first boot apart from my ethernet adapter which is a pcmcia card. It's a fairly generic adapter (PC line) and what I was wondering was is there a way to get linux to support it from within the new install rather than go back to the livecd?

If there isn't then what are the steps I need to do to ensure my linux install will support this ethernet card? I set up the installation via a ssh terminal on another computer so whatever was in the livecd definitely supported it.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the [handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/index.xml), you only need to go to

`/usr/src/linux`

and run `make menuconfig` there. On the list, add support for the chip the card uses under device drivers and enable PCMCIA under bus options. [Here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=7#doc_chap3) a tutorial on that.

After that run

`make && make modules_install` and copy the kernel image over the existing kernel image and reboot.